# A trouble with orchestral imagine for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider, laravel-5.3

I have a problem with orchestral imagine for laravel (https://github.com/orchestral/imagine). It's a wripper for imagine component, so I had been caught an error:

```
Class 'Orchestra\Imagine\ImagineServiceProvider' not found
```

what I doing wrong?!

I had been added nesseccary lines to config/app.php including this line.

Answer (score 0):

So, solution is a right version of the extension. For Laravel 5.2 It's 3.2